# How to extract multiple information from the \jobname

Tags: conditionals, jobname

I use one .tex file to create multiple CV depending on the `\jobname`.
For that I use the `ifthen` package and for each type of CV I create a Boolean value that I use to conditionally include some text.
Now I want to make my tex file multilingual (french and english) so the `\jobname` will contain two information the job itself and the language name. For that I want to use regex. But I don't succeed to perform a regex in `\jobname`?
So can you help me to apply a regex on a jobname like `<jobname>-<lang`
So currently I have this code

```tex
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
----
\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{ingmod}}{\jobname}}{\DEVtrue}{}
----
```

And I use the `\DEVtrue` (and the other Boolean for conditional compila now I want to define the argument to pass to babel using conditional compilation. with the `lang` part of the `\jobname`.
Of course, I use a `Makefile` to wrap the `latexmk` commands for each compilation.

Comment: do you need a regex or just split on `-` ?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please make a small example explaining in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added more explanation in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have main file named `foo-bar.tex` and you need to check if the first part of the job name is `foo`. You can do this by following macros:

```
\def\readjobname #1-#2\end{\def\name{#1}\def\lang{#2}}
\def\isname #1\iftrue{\edef\tmp{\detokenize{#1}}\ifx\tmp\name}

\expandafter\readjobname \jobname\end  % reading both parts of the job name

\isname ingmod\iftrue Name is ingmod\else Name isn't ingmod\fi

\isname foo\iftrue Name is foo\else Name isn't foo\fi

\bye
```

The example above assumes that the job name must be in the form `foo-bar`. If the hyphen `-` is missing here, then it fails. But you can do the macro more robust:

```
\def\readjobname #1-#2\end{\def\name{#1}\def\lang{#2}}
\def\isname #1\iftrue{\edef\tmp{\detokenize{#1}}\ifx\tmp\name}
\def\isindash #1-#2\iffalse{\ifx\relax#2\relax}

\expandafter\isindash \jobname-\iffalse  % reading job name
   \edef\name{\jobname}\def\lang{}
\else
   \expandafter\readjobname \jobname\end
\fi

\isname ingmod\iftrue Name is ingmod\else Name isn't ingmod\fi

\isname foo\iftrue Name is foo\else Name isn't foo\fi

\bye
```

Now, if there isn't hyphen character then name is full jobname and \lang is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine even though I don't understand all the code. I don't know the syntax of the `\def` command. I'm used to using `\newcommand` and `\newdocumentcommand`.

Comment: @mveril `\def` is TeX priitive command for defining macros. LaTeX is macro package. `\newcommand` is a LaTeX macro which checks if the defined control sequence is defined already and if not then the macro processes `\def` internally.